# after adding a button to my pygame, several things that previously gave me no issues are now giving me errors?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pygame

im not sure why im getting errors, as it was working perfectly fine before i started to add a button to my game. Ultimately my goal is to create a game menu with the options to start game which then moves onto the next screen, the level platform, and quit, which ultimately will close the window. Bonus, if i can get help on this, im thinking about also creating a sign up and login page, i already have one set up using tkinter but im not sure how to access the stored information using pygames, so it saves game progress from username and password. Also, what website do you guys use to get free images for your games? I can't draw that well and am having trouble finding images that match what im trying to accomplish.

```py
# imports
import pygame, sys
import pygame.freetype 
from pygame.sprite import Sprite 
from pygame.rect import Rect

# colors
green = (0, 255, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)

# buttons
def create_text(text, font_size, text_color, bg_color):
    font = pygame.freetype.Sysfont("Courioer", font_size, bold=True)
    surface, _ = font.render(text=text, fgcolor=text_color, bgcolor = bg_color)
    return surface.convert_alpha()

class UIElement(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, center_position, text, font_size, bg_color, text_color):
        
        super().__init__()
        
        self.mouse_over = False

        default_image = create_text(text, font_size, text_color, bg_text)


        highlighted_image = create_text(text, font_size * 1.2, text_color, bg_text)

        self.images = [default_image, highlighted_image]
        self.rects = [
            default_image.get_rect(center = center_position), 
            highlighted_image.get_rect(center = center_position)]

        super().__init__()

    @property 
    def image(self):
        return self.image[1] if self.mouse_over else self.image[0]
    
    @property 
    def rect(self):
        return self.rects[1] if self.mouse_over else self.rects[0]

    def update(self, mouse_pos):
        if self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.mouse_over = True
        else:
            self.mouse_over = False 

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

# Title
pygame.display.set_caption("Zombrio")
icon = pygame.image.load("zombie.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)


# character
survivorImg = pygame.image.load("frankenstein.png")
survivorx = 1
survivory = 400

def player(): 
    screen.blit(survivorImg, (survivorx, survivory))

def main():
    pygame.init()

    # screen 
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    uielement = UIElement(
        center_position = (400, 400),
        font_size = 30,
        bg_color = black,
        text_color = green,
        text = "Start"
    )

    # Game Loop
    while True:

        screen.fill(black) # not defined error, only occurred after creating buttons

        for event in pygame.event.get(): # video system not initialized
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # indent error
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        uielement.update(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) # says uielement is not defined
        uielement.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

        player()


        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(120)

main()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Write [comments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html) rather than strings.

Comment: Just a heads up: looks like "Courioer" should be "Courier" in your create_text function.

Comment: @Rabbid76, i agree, i should have wrote comments rather than a string, but converting it into a comment rather than a string will not fix my current issue.

Answer (score 2):

So """Text""" is a string literal. You can use it for multi-line strings.

[https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings#:~:text=String%20literals%20inside%20triple%20quotes,go%20to%20represent%20computed%20values](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings#:%7E:text=String%20literals%20inside%20triple%20quotes,go%20to%20represent%20computed%20values).

You can also use it to create a docstring.

The way you are using it here does not look correct. If you want to print those statements, then trying print("""Text""") on the next line.

If you want to use it as a comment on a line of code, then follow it with the "#"

For more examples of using tripple quotes, see here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/triple-quotes-in-python/

Comment: thank you, i know how strings work, i was using them to show where the error was occurring, although, should have used # instead. However, this doesn't answer my question, or fix my issue even if I were to change those strings into comments.